# pd.read_csv killed when Reading large files

Tags: python, pandas, boto3

I have 30 each has 2 gb of data compressed files in s3 location and I'm trying to decompress the files, convert them to data frames and then want to subset the data based on column names. When I'm running the code it is getting Killed(Please refer the screenshot for error)[image]. Please help me out how to convert the files to data frames.

```
def run():
    with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=len(source_keys)) as executor:
        jobs = [executor.submit(move_source_to_dest, source_keys[i],src_session) for i in range(len(source_keys))]
        jobs_categorize = futures.wait(jobs, timeout=6000)
        if jobs_categorize.not_done:
            print("one job didn't complete with-in time-out")
        for job in jobs_categorize.done:
            key = job.result()
            if key:
                print("Compelted {}".format(os.path.basename(key)))



def move_source_to_dest(key, src_session):
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tempdir:
        try:
            print("downloading {}/{}".format(s3_src_bucket, key))
            src_session.client('s3').download_file(Bucket=s3_src_bucket, Key=key,
                                                   Filename=os.path.join(tempdir, os.path.basename(key)))

        #Command to decompress the files
        command = "bzip2 -dk " + os.path.join(tempdir, os.path.basename(key))
        subprocess.call(command,shell = True)

        #Reading all the columns names from the file "ambs_ambi_ColumnsNames.txt"    
        file = open('ambs_ambi_ColumnsNames.txt','r')
        clist=file.readlines()

        Filename=os.path.join(tempdir, os.path.basename(key[:-4]))
        Fileout=os.path.join(tempdir, os.path.basename(key[:-4])) + "-out.csv" 
        print("Creating the DataFrame")

        df=pd.read_csv(Filename, sep="\x01", names=clist)

        #Give all the column names that are required in the file named 'ambs_ambi_OutColumnsNames.txt' 
        file = open('ambs_ambi_OutColumnsNames.txt','r')
        outcols=file.readlines()
        print("subseting the data")
        data=df.loc[:,outcols]
        data.to_csv(Fileout,sep='\x01')

        print("Uploading to {}/{}".format(s3_dest_bucket, os.path.join(s3_dest_prefix, os.path.basename(Fileout))))
        src_session.client('s3').upload_file(Filename=Fileout,
                                              Bucket=s3_dest_bucket,
                                              Key=os.path.join(s3_dest_prefix, os.path.basename(Fileout)),
                                              ExtraArgs={"ServerSideEncryption": "AES256"})
    except Exception as e:
        print("exception handling {}/{}".format(s3_src_bucket, key))
        raise e
return key
```

Comment: First check, do you have enough ram? You can check via top in bash or task manager on windows.

Comment: I'm using my server where I put 80 gb ram